# android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollViewWithFixedFling cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

Как вы уже поняли не получается найти класс `NestedScrollViewWithFixedFling`, который якобы должен быть внутри `android.support.v4.widget` исходя из реверс инженеринга. Может при реверсе класс `NestedScrollView` переименовывается на `NestedScrollViewWithFixedFling`?

```
import android.databinding.DataBindingComponent;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollViewWithFixedFling;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class FragmentHotelPricesBinding extends ViewDataBinding {
    private static final IncludedLayouts sIncludes;
    private static final SparseIntArray sViewsWithIds;
    public final FrameLayout contentContainer;
    private long mDirtyFlags;
    private final FrameLayout mboundView0;
    public final RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public final NestedScrollViewWithFixedFling scrollView;

    static {
        sIncludes = null;
        (sViewsWithIds = new SparseIntArray()).put(R.id.scroll_view, 1);
        FragmentHotelPricesBinding.sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.content_container, 2);
        FragmentHotelPricesBinding.sViewsWithIds.put(R.id.recycler_view, 3);
    }

    public FragmentHotelPricesBinding(final DataBindingComponent dataBindingComponent, final View rootTag) {
        super(dataBindingComponent, rootTag, 0);
        this.mDirtyFlags = -1L;
        final Object[] mapBindings = ViewDataBinding.mapBindings(dataBindingComponent, rootTag, 4, FragmentHotelPricesBinding.sIncludes, FragmentHotelPricesBinding.sViewsWithIds);
        this.contentContainer = (FrameLayout) mapBindings[2];
        (this.mboundView0 = (FrameLayout) mapBindings[0]).setTag(null);
        this.recyclerView = (RecyclerView) mapBindings[3];
        this.scrollView = (NestedScrollViewWithFixedFling) mapBindings[1];
        this.setRootTag(rootTag);
        this.invalidateAll();
    }

    public static FragmentHotelPricesBinding bind(final View view) {
        return bind(view, DataBindingUtil.getDefaultComponent());
    }

    public static FragmentHotelPricesBinding bind(final View view, final DataBindingComponent dataBindingComponent) {
        if (!"layout/fragment_hotel_prices_0".equals(view.getTag())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("view tag isn't correct on view:" + view.getTag());
        }
        return new FragmentHotelPricesBinding(dataBindingComponent, view);
    }

    public static FragmentHotelPricesBinding inflate(final LayoutInflater layoutInflater) {
        return inflate(layoutInflater, DataBindingUtil.getDefaultComponent());
    }

    public static FragmentHotelPricesBinding inflate(final LayoutInflater layoutInflater, final DataBindingComponent dataBindingComponent) {
        return bind(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hotel_prices, null, false), dataBindingComponent);
    }
public static FragmentHotelPricesBinding inflate(final LayoutInflater layoutInflater, final ViewGroup viewGroup, final boolean b) {
    return inflate(layoutInflater, viewGroup, b, DataBindingUtil.getDefaultComponent());
}

public static FragmentHotelPricesBinding inflate(final LayoutInflater layoutInflater, final ViewGroup viewGroup, final boolean b, final DataBindingComponent dataBindingComponent) {
    return DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.fragment_hotel_prices, viewGroup, b, dataBindingComponent);
}

@Override
protected void executeBindings() {
    synchronized (this) {
        this.mDirtyFlags = 0L;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean hasPendingBindings() {
    synchronized (this) {
        return this.mDirtyFlags != 0L;
    }
}

@Override
public void invalidateAll() {
    synchronized (this) {
        this.mDirtyFlags = 1L;
        // monitorexit(this)
        this.requestRebind();
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean onFieldChange(final int n, final Object o, final int n2) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean setVariable(final int n, final Object o) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Вы хоть ссылку дайте на то место где вы его нашли и поясните зачем оно вам.

Comment: любопытство ради, добавил код

Comment: В сорцах гугла я этот класс не нашёл. Приведите таки ссылку.

Comment: я же говорю это просто декомпилированный класс, импорт почему то делает от саппорта 4